# EncodeFor in cfoutput disables html in general why?

Tags: html, coldfusion, cfml, esapi

Recently I updated from ColdFusion 11 to ColdFusion 2016 because I wanted to use `encodefor=""` in my `cfoutput` tags. Everything works correctly except HTML. For example:

- `<br>` tags that are from a variable will be shown as `<br>` text instead of a line break.
- `/r/n` from MySQL will somehow be converted to `<br>` and have the same problem as mentioned above.

Is there a way to configure ESAPI or even ColdFusion to ignore `<br>`? I browsed the web and can't find an answer to my problem.

**More examples:**

```
<!--- This works fine! --->
<h3>Example 1</h3>
<cfset testvariable = "firstline <br> secondline">
<cfoutput>#testvariable#</cfoutput>

<!--- This does not work--->
<h3>Example 2</h3>
<cfoutput encodefor="html">#testvariable#</cfoutput>

<!--- This does not work either --->
<h3>Example 3</h3>
<cfoutput>#encodeforhtml(testvariable)#</cfoutput>
```

**Expected results:**

```
firstline
secondline
```

**Actual results:**

```
firstline <br> secondline
```

---

**EDIT**

This works for me!

```
<cfoutput encodefor="html">
   #WithoutHTML#
   <cfoutput>#getsafeHTML(WithHTML)#</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: That's what `encodeForHTML()` does. It escapes the HTML so it doesn't render on the page to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks. It is not intended to be used for all `<cfoutput>`.  You should only be using it to encode specific sections of your code where needed. Like within `<input>` tags, are within HTML tag attributes. etc.

Comment: Yes, thats what I expected but Its a huge project from like 2005 with thousands of variables. I needed an solution that I dont have to edit every single one.

But I'm happy with my Solution

Comment: You should only need it when output something that came from the client. Any data that you don't trust.

Comment: Thats what it is, like 80% of the variables is User input. 
Its much less time consuming fixing the other 20% then everyone you know.

Not the best/right or even an good solution but it works really well .

Comment: I would use Canonicalize() instead of getSafeHTML()

Answer (score 0):

"@Lucas - There is no option to ignore. But suggest to create one function to return text by replacing the 
 back using REReplaceNoCase.
Please check the below extension to your 3 examples.

#### Example 4

#REReplaceNoCase(encodeforhtml(testvariable), ""<br[^>]*>"", ""
"", ""all"")#"